# How to test that two elements have the same width using cypress

Tags: cypress

I have an responsive application where i using a specific viewport want to verify that two elements have the same width. How can i do this?

i´ve tried extracting the width using `window.getComputedStyle` but the returned value is "auto"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cy.get('Element1').then(($el) => {
  cy.get('Element2').should(($el2) => {
    expect($el2).to.have.css('width', $el1.width());
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that ?

```
cy.get('Element1').should(($el) => {
  expect($el).to.have.css('width', ...)
}))

cy.get('Element2').should(($el2) => {
  expect($el2).to.have.css('width', ...)
}))
```

Comment: hmm, that only checks if width has an specific width, ex. "16px", and the width will be an string

Comment: yes sorry, i am a beginner in Cypress, Arnon Axelrod Solution seems better